# Add social count values in a single div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found a PEN http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/iefKk/, where social shares count through jQuery. I want to add all count value in a single div. How can I do this?

```
    <div class="share">
  Twitter - <span class="twCount">0</span> <br>
 Facebook - <span class="fbCount">0</span> <br>
  Pintrest - <span class="prCount">0</span><br>
  Linkedin - <span class="liCount">0</span>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
(function () {
    var countUp, setCount, url;
    url = 'http://www.digitalindia.gov.in/';
    $.getJSON('http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function (json) {
        return setCount($('.twCount'), json.count);

    });
    $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/' + url, function (json) {
        return setCount($('.fbCount'), json.shares);
    });
    $.getJSON('http://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function (json) {
        return setCount($('.prCount'), json.count);
    });
    $.getJSON('http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' + url + '&callback=?', function (json) {
        return setCount($('.liCount'), json.count);
    });

    countUp = function ($item) {
        return setTimeout(function () {
            var current, newCount, target;
            current = $item.attr('data-current-count') * 1;
            target = $item.attr('data-target-count') * 1;
            newCount = current + Math.ceil((target - current) / 2);
            $item.attr('data-current-count', newCount);
            $item.html(newCount);
            if (newCount < target) {
                return countUp($item);
            }
        }, 100);
    };
    setCount = function ($item, count) {
        if (count == null) {
            count = null;
        }
        $item.attr('data-target-count', count);
        $item.attr('data-current-count', 0);
        return countUp($item);

    };
} .call(this));

//@ sourceURL=pen.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an add function in the setCount method, since it has been calling after each getJSON success ,

```
setCount = function ($item, count) {
    $("#total").text(parseInt($("#total").text().trim()) + count);
    if (count == null) {
        count = null;
    }
    $item.attr('data-target-count', count);
    $item.attr('data-current-count', 0);
    return countUp($item);

};
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c0qp3q1o/6/)